# How can I capture file opened event on win7 OS

Tags: c#, windows, events, windows-7

I want to be aware of the particular file was opened. After opening the file I would like to perform some operations. Can I make a script in this process? How? Any Source?

Comment: Was opened where? By your program or from outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileSystemWatcher:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7t1d0ky.aspx

Comment: I don't see how this helps. The FSW doesn't raise file opened events as far as I can see does it?

Comment: @fallenidol Are you sure about that? It looks like there is an "accessed" event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx

Comment: Yeah I experimented with that but it doesn't seem to work. Apparently, "This method may return an inaccurate value, because it uses native functions whose values may not be continuously updated by the operating system."


[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastaccesstime.aspx)